# use variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

I have this simple HTML layout:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 //alert(check_permisssions());
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var publish;
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
       appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
       FB.api(
          "/me/permissions",
          function (response) {
             if(response && !response.error) {
                var publish = '1';
             }
             else {
                var publish = '0';
             }
          }
      );
    });
 };

 (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

 alert(publish);

 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I want to use the variable called `publish` outside the `FB.api` function. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to alert the variable like above but it's logging that the variable has no value.

Comment: As I told you when answering your earlier question: You can't use `publish` until **after** it's been filled in by the `api` callback. Also, don't redeclare it inside the callback, you'll shadow it.

Comment: It's already filled as alerting it inside the function works. I want to use it instead out of the function but not necessarily in the HEAD like the previous question. How to do this?

Comment: I see that you using jQuery. You can use Defered object. This is much elegant way. I have prepared this example for you:  http://pastebin.com/41YCNRFq